# Problema com subpastas e reescrita de url com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, htaccess

Estou tentando fazer o `Laravel 4` rodar num subdiretório, usando o .htaccess para poder reescrever a url para a pasta public

Exemplo:

- `C:\xammp\htdocs\laravel4`
- O `.htaccess` está em reescrevendo  `C:\xammp\htdocs\laravel4` para `C:\xammp\htdocs\laravel4\public`

Funciona corretamente para a reescrita. Porém, quando tento no arquivo `routes.php` criar uma configuração, sempre retorna página não encontrada.

Exemplo:

Se eu acessar `localhost/laravel4/teste`, com a configuração abaixo, o Laravel diz que a página não foi encontrada.

```
Route::get('/teste', function(){

 return "Hello World";
});
```

Agora, quando eu faço dessa maneira abaixo, ele mostra corretamente:

```
Route::get('laravel4/teste', function(){
   return "Hello Word";
});
```

Entre testes e outros, descobri que o Laravel 4, quando vai routear a url, não usa o `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`(que retornaria apenas os parâmetros depois do **public/index.php** reescrito), mas sim o `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (que retornaria tudo que vem depois do `http://localhost/`).

Então, eu consigo reescrever a url, porém não consigo configurar as rotas normalmente, mas apenas quando uso um prefixo referente à subpasta que eu estou usando.

Como resolver esse problema sem ter que alterar núcleo do Laravel 4?

Há alguma maneira de ignorar ou prefixar essas rotas internamente (Algum método na classe Route ou alguma configuração global) ?

Comment: Tente com `teste` ao invés de `/teste`.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti, fiz isso, mas o resultado foi o mesmo (só funciona com o prefixo indesejado). Parece que, internamente, o Laravel4 já trata essas barras.

Comment: Não acho uma boa idéia expor toda sua aplicação numa pasta liberada para internet. Você pode fazer um vhost apontando diretamente para a pasta public do laravel, além de mais seguro não terá outros problemas

Comment: @gmsantos, eu pensei também nessa possibilidade, mas, no desenvolvimento local, é bom adequarmos a aplicação para aquilo que ele será em produção; e, em produção, num servidor compartilhado, ninguém tem acesso a um vhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, depois de tentar, tentar e tentar, acabei apelando para a seguinte solução.

No caso de querer configurar o `Laravel 4` dentro de um subdiretório, temos que fazer uma pequena alteração na pasta `bootstrap/start.php` e adicionar o seguinte código antes de tudo que está declarado:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {

    $prefixed_uri = basename(dirname(__DIR__)) . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL'] = $prefixed_uri;

}
```

Faço isso porque o `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`, que é utilizado no `Laravel 4`, utiliza, no método `prepareRequestUri`, o header `HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL` para poder obter a URI atual.

Não sei se definir essa variável pode ocasionar algum problema, mas essa foi a única solução encontrada.

Comment: Já sei! Isso é uma grande gambiarra.

Comment: Outras maneiras interessantes de se fazer isso http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host (particularmente gosto da primeira)