# Rodando o Silex no provedor compartilhado

Tags: php, apache, silex

Acabei de subir um site para a Locaweb numa hospedagem simples e compartilhada Linux, só que para variar não funcionou.

Imagino que seja porque o index não está no raiz do site, e sim dentro da pasta `public`.
Pergunta: Como eu faço para fazer o index dentro do `public` funcionar, já que não tenho como mudar a configuração do virtualhost?

Obrigado
Ps. o htaccess esta assim:

```
RewriteEngine on
#AddHandler php53-script .php .php5 .php53 .pht .phtm .phtml
#suPHP_ConfigPath /home/site1389376316/
AddHandler php55-script .php
DirectoryIndex public/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

---

Consegui resolver em partes o problema. Fiz uma pequena alteração no htaccess.

Removi esta linha:

```
DirectoryIndex public/index.php
```

E alterei esta:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

Desta forma o site carrega mas por consequência os arquivos de imagem, css, js que estam todos na pasta public não são encontrados.

O que eu posso fazer?

Comment: Falei aqui deum problema parecido no Laravel. E pelo visto, o `Silex` também usa o `Symphony`. Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43685/problema-com-subpastas-e-reescrita-de-url-com-laravel

Comment: Já tentou `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?p=$1`?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu tentei sim. So que ai quando eu escrevo silex.dominio.com/admin por exemplo ele da um erro interno e a url muda para silex.dominio.com/admin/?p=admin. Tem alguma ideia de que pode ser isto?

Comment: Tente subir um nível sua estrutura de diretórios e alterar o public para a pasta public_html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estava com o mesmo problema, a unica diferença é que minha pasta assets com css, img, javascript e etc, esta na raiz fora da pasta public/web (não sei o impacto que isso vai ter com relação a padrões ...). 
Para testar no localhost criei uma virtual host, mas já testei no servidor e tb funcionou. 
Para resolver o problema da pasta css dentro da pasta web talvez acrescentar essa linha resolva :

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/css/
```

A solução não é minha, pesquisei em tantos lugares e testei tantas combinações, e não guardei a fonte de onde encontrei a solução.

Minha estrutura de pastas ficou mais ou menos assim :

- RAIZ

  - assets
  - src
  - vendor
  - view
  - web

E o .htaccess (na raiz do site) ficou assim :

```
    DirectoryIndex /web/index.php

< IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
    RewriteRule (.*) /web/?$1

< /IfModule>

< IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    < IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /web/index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    < /IfModule>
< /IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido.
Mudei para um plano de Revendas ai la eu posso alterar o document_root do site e tudo certo agora.

Obrigado