# Laravel 5 - Remover public da URL

Tags: laravel, htaccess, laravel-5

Desenvolvi uma formulário e preciso "jogá-lo" no **servidor de produção**. Não possuo nenhum tipo de acesso ao servidor(Linux, Slackware). Faço o acesso a minha aplicação pela url http://ip_do_servidor/meus_projetos/questionario/public. Com o script abaixo eu recebo apenas a mensagem `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.` `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:`. Gostaria de saber como posso fazer com que a página seja carregada sem precisar usar o `/public` e saber também se preciso reestruturar as páginas dele para ficar um pouco mais seguro.

Esse .htaccess eu deixei na raiz do meu projeto

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Esse está dentro de public/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43685/problema-com-subpastas-e-reescrita-de-url-com-laravel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existem algumas formas de deploy de uma aplicação feita com Laravel. Por ordem de recomendação, seguem as opções.

*As opções de deploy abaixo são para o **Laravel 5**. Não sei se funcionam em outras versões.*

---

### Setando o DocumentRoot para a pasta /public

**Essa é a forma recomendada pelo time do Laravel** e a mais segura de todas. Não há necessidade de alterar arquivos `.htaccess`, basta usar o padrão do Laravel e pronto. A única coisa a ser feita é configurar o seu Apache. No VirtualHosts faça apontar o `DocumentRoot` para a pasta `public` da seguinte maneira:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
   DocumentRoot "/path/to/app/public"

   <Directory "/path/to/app/public">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

### Usando alias e .htaccess

Uma forma de deploy sem mexer no `DocumentRoot` é usando aliases do Apache e setando um .`htaccess` dentro da pasta public um pouco diferente do `.htaccess` padrão. Usando *Alias*, seu VirtualHost ficaria parecido com esse abaixo:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
   DocumentRoot "/path/to/apps"

   Alias /app1 "/path/to/apps/app1/public"
   <Directory "/path/to/apps/app1/public">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>

   Alias /app2 "/path/to/apps/app1/public"
   <Directory "/path/to/apps/app1/public>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Dessa forma você pode colocar várias aplicações no mesmo `DocumentRoot` e separada por diretórios. Em cada aplicação, no diretório `public`, precisaria setar os `.htaccess` da seguinte forma:

#### Aplicação 1:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /app1

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

#### Aplicação 2:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /app2

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Suas aplicações responderiam nas URLS http://www.example.com/app1 e http://www.example.com/app2. Repare bem nos `.htaccess` na linha `RewriteBase /app2`. Isso é para corrigir um problema de paginação do próprio Laravel.

---

### Movendo os arquivos da pasta public

**Essa é forma menos recomendada**, pois ela abre brechas de segurança. Entretanto, vamos a ela. **Use por sua conta e risco.**

1. Copie todo o conteúdo da pasta public para a raiz do seu projeto.
2. Abra o arquivo `index.php` na raiz do projeto e faça as seguintes modificações

De:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

Para:

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/start.php';
```

Essa solução vai permitir fazer request para qualquer arquivo na sua raiz, inclusive o arquivo `.env`. Experimente acessar (http://example.com/app/.env) e você verá suas informações de conexão de banco de dados lá!

Você terá que proteger todos os arquivos que você não quer request direto usando o `.htaccess`. Não testei, mas acredito que dessa forma:

```
RewriteRule \.(.env)$ - [F]
```

Mais uma vez, **não recomendo essa solução.** Tente entrar em contato com ser host e peça para apontar o Document Root da URL para a pasta public. Use por sua conta e risco.

Comment: Tendo acesso ao servidor, só usando o virtualhost do modo que você disse já apresenta mais segurança ? Não existe nenhum meio mais seguro ?

Comment: Segurança é algo relativo, pois mesmo aplicando a primeira solução não garante 100% de segurança. Mas comparativamente, a primeira solução é sim mais segura que todas as outras.

O Laravel em si foi projetado para rodar da primeira forma. As outras são "hacks" em cima do framework. Não existe uma solução alternativa a primeira solução que o time do Laravel ofereça. #sadbuttrue

Comment: Eu sei que alguns Hosts, oferecem a possibilidade de apontar a pasta que você deseja como DocumentRoot quando você cria um novo subdomínio. Essa é uma boa alternativa. Você pode criar o subdomínio http://app.example.com e apontar o Document Root desse subdomínio para a pasta public,