# Url requisição Ajax apontar para uma rota laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

Configurei a seguinte rota no meu arquivo de rotas:

```
Route::post('order/productsByCategory', ['uses'=>'OrderController@productsByCategory']);
```

Como eu faço para utiliza-la na minha requisição Ajax ?

```
$.ajax({
        url: "",
        type: 'POST',
        data: "",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': laravel_token
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**:
Alterei a rota para:

```
Route::post('Order/productsByCategory', ['as' => 'productsByCategory', 'uses'=>'OrderController@productsByCategory']);
```

E a requisição para:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '{{ route("productsByCategory") }}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { id: categoryId},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': laravel_token
        },
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Porém aconteceu o seguinte erro:

```
POST http://localhost/manapasteis2/public/%7B%7B%20route(%22productsByCategory%22)%20%7D%7D 403 (Forbidden)
```

Comment: Creio que seja `$.ajax({
        url: "/order/productsByCategory",`, a barra no começo é para evitar o caminho relativo, se funcionar me avise

Comment: qual a extensão do arquivo q tem o código js?

Comment: O arquivo é .js mesmo @gmsantos

Comment: Matou a charada! Veja a resposta do @GuilhermeNascimento :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar `{{ route("apelidoDaRota") }}` não funciona dentro de um arquivo `.js`, e notei que vc está usando o public ao invés de configurar o `VirtualHost` no Apache/Ngnix então você terá que fazer assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/manapasteis2/public/order/productsByCategory',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { id: categoryId},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': laravel_token
    },
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Se configurar no `VirtualHost` e apontar diretamente a pasta `public` então precisará só fazer isto:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/order/productsByCategory',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { id: categoryId},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': laravel_token
    },
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Aqui tem algumas dicas de como configurar o `VirtualHost`:

- [Laravel 5 - Remover public da URL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57830/3635)

Answer (score 0):

Adicione um alias:

```
Route::post('order/productsByCategory', ['as' => 'apelidoDaRota', 'uses'=>'OrderController@productsByCategory']);
```

Chame pelo alias:

```
url: "{{ route("apelidoDaRota") }}",
```

Comment: Não funcionou :/ Editei a pergunta com os códigos que tenho.