# Laravel e Ajax - Duvida sobre rota

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Utilizando a Framework laravel 5.5, Como eu faço para chamar a seguinte rota no Ajax?

Rota:

```
Route::group(['prefix' =>'paineladmin', 'namespace' =>'PainelAdmin', ], function(){

Route::post('galeriaArquivos', 'GaleriaimgController@arquivos')->name('galeriaArquivos');

});
```

Código Ajax

```
function buscar($tamanho){
    // repassando as variaveis do php  
    var pasta = $('#pasta').val();  
    var tamanho = $tamanho;  


    // utilizando o split para quebrar o diretorio e receber somente o nome da pasta
    var dirimg = pasta.split("/galeriaimg/");

    var caminho = '/paineladmin/galeriaimg/arquivos';
    var diri =  '/images/'+tamanho+'/galeriaimg/';

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    var data = {
      tamanho: tamanho,
      diretorio: dirimg[1], 
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',  
        url: caminho,      
            data:data,
            success: function(result){ 

               $.each(result, function(key, value){
                    var container = '<div class="col-md-4" id="col-'+key+'">';
                    container +=        '<div class="img-wrap">';
                    container +=            '<img src="'+diri+dirimg[1]+'/'+value+'" class="img-return" alt="galeria" "/>';    
                    container +=            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm delete" onclick="excluir('+key+')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>'; 
                    container +=         '</div>';    

                    container +=         '<input type="hidden" name="imagemgaleria['+key+'][endereco]" value="/galeriaimg/'+dirimg[1]+'/'+value+'" />';    
                    container +=         '<input type="text" placeholder="Título Imagem" name="imagemgaleria['+key+'][tituloimagem]" class="form-control required inputgaleria" />';   
                    container +=         '<textarea name="imagemgaleria['+key+'][descricao]" placeholder="Descricao" class="form-control inputgaleria" ></textarea>';   
                    container +=    '</div>';   

                    $('#galeriaimg').append(container);
               });

               /* monstrando os botoes que foram ocultados.*/
               $('.oculto').show();
              $('.group').remove();
         }
    });
}
```

já tentei chamar por `{{ route('galeriaArquivos') }}` ou seguindo os dados desses post [link Stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192888/url-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-apontar-para-uma-rota-laravel)

Comment: Dá um php artisan route:list e e pega a rota correta.

Comment: @marcosXavier  obrigado! fiz o que vc passou e consegui resolver! ficou assim no arquivo ajax  var caminho = 'galeriaArquivos'; abraços,

Comment: Perfeito. Poderia detalhar melhor como resolveu, talvez ajude alguém. Acredito que usando algo como caminho = {{route(model.galeriaArquivos)}} também funcionaria. Precisaria ver a saída do comando que sugeri.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Está tão básica a pergunta que fica até difícil de imaginar que seja isso:
A `URL` correta a ser chamada é:

> http://localhost/PASTA_DO_PROJETO/PASTA_ONDE_INSTALOU_O_LARAVEL/public/paineladmin/galeriaArquivos

Aí retorna o que vc quer, fiz o teste assim:

```
Route::group(['prefix' =>'paineladmin', 'namespace' =>'PainelAdmin', ], function(){
    Route::get('galeriaArquivos', function () {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'FUNCIONA',  API Rest', 'status' => 'Conectado']);;
    })->name('galeriaArquivosa');
});
```

Comment: ola! da forma que vc passou não funciona, mas consegui retornar colocando o caminho dessa forma no arquivo Ajax,  var caminho = 'galeriaArquivos';

Comment: Que estranho, fiz o teste no meu projeto antes de te enviar, aqui eu consegui chamar de boa como te falei, tô usando laravel 5.4

Comment: tranquilo! o importante é que consegui resolver! =] aqui estou usando o laravel 5.5, obrigado! abraços