# Ubuntu 16.04 Lumen PHP e Apache, só funciona a rota / as outras não funcionam

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, lumen

Olá, uso Ubuntu 16.04 e instalei o apache e o Lumen. Criei um projeto teste do Lumen chamado financas.

A pasta do projeto está na pasta /var/www/html/sub-zero/financas

quando acesso no meu browser localhost/sub-zero/financas/public, o retorno é ok...

porém, quando eu tento acessar localhost/sub-zero/financas/a (que é uma rota que eu criei pra testar) tenho um retorno de erro 404.

Já habilitei o mod_rewrite do apache...

o erro retornado:
    The requested URL /var/www/html/sub-zero/financas/public/index.php was not found on this server.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Já tentei virtualhosts, mas devo estar fazendo errado, pq não funciona por nada

Comment: A pergunta pode ser sobre Lumen, mas a configuração do Laravel e Lumen é idêntica, basta ajustar pelo Apache http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57871/3635, se for um servidor shared como este populares, basta mover o conteudo de public na public_html e o resto fora dela, como expliquei aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91799/3635

Comment: Se em ``localhost/sub-zero/financas/public`` tá funcionando, o lógico é que vai funcionar ``localhost/sub-zero/financas/public/a`` e não ``localhost/sub-zero/financas/a``.

Comment: @Daniel me enganei ali, o localhost/sub-zero/financas/public/a que não funciona mesmo...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento no caso, está no Apache local, na minha máquina mesmo... Mover os arquivos da pasta public para a pasta raiz, não resolveu

Comment: Descobri aqui, no meu .htaccess, tive que comentar a linha

RewriteBase /var/www/html/sub-zero/financas/public/

Comment: @JDalri mover os arquivos eu deixei bem claro que era em servidores SHARED. Se atente com mais atenção ao que foi escrito por favor. Nos links que postei tem várias soluções como o VirtualHost+DocumentRoot ou usar o proprio .htaccess para "remover" o public da url.