# APP_URL do .env registar URL inteira (além do dominio) da aplicação

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, url, laravel-5.3, configuração

Tenho um servidor com um dominio onde existem varias aplicações Laravel, pro exemplo, o caminho da aplicação1 fica assim: https://dominio.com/aplicacao1/public

O problema é que quando boto no APP_URL=https://dominio.com/aplicacao1/public o app_url só gera as rotas com o dominio, por exemplo se eu gerar `url('foo/bar')` o link vai ficar https://dominio.com/foo/bar (desconsiderando o caminho da aplicação - `aplicacao1/public`)...

Alguem já viu este problema?

Comment: Isso te ajuda amigo? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57830/laravel-5-remover-public-da-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível que você tenha que criar subdomínios pra cada aplicação.
Ex: https://aplicacao1.dominio.com.br
https://aplicacao2.dominio.com.br

Comment: Seria uma solução, mas no caso não da pra ser assim pq são varias aplicações de pessoas diferentes e não é em uma hospedagem "profissional", daria muito trabalho fazer subdominios para todas as aplicações...