# Problemas com .htaccess ao ocultar pasta public laravel 5.4

Tags: htaccess, xampp, laravel-5.4, virtualhost, public

Preciso fazer o deploy para produção de uma aplicação que migrei para o laravel 5.4, em ambiente de teste estou utilizando o virtual host no windows onde digito na url 'meusite1' e até então beleza.

Porém quando fui configurar com o .htaccess ao acessar a aplicação pela url 'meusite1' os arquivos do ajax por exemplo perdem a referencia e apontam para o DocumentRoot que no caso é htdocs e não htdocs\meusite1, e assim que obrigam a escrever no código de uma imagem por exemplo: 'meusite1/img/banner.png' e não apenas 'img/banner.png'

Como estou trabalhando com duas aplicações utilizei a resposta do link **[Laravel 5 - Remover public da URL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57830/laravel-5-remover-public-da-url)**

Configurei o VirtualHosts do apache assim:

   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
   DocumentRoot "/htdocs"

Alias /meusite1 "/htdocs/meusite1/public"
   
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted

Alias /meusite2 "/htdocs/meusite2/public"
   
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted

No arquivo .htaccess da pasta public dentro do meu meusite1 está assim:

    
        Options -MultiViews

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /meusite1

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz de onde estou errando?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Lista de diretórios do projeto em Laravel é exibida ao invés de executar a aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91795/lista-de-diret%c3%b3rios-do-projeto-em-laravel-%c3%a9-exibida-ao-inv%c3%a9s-de-executar-a-aplic)