# Publicar Laravel 5 em uma subpasta

Tags: laravel

Preciso publicar um sistema que eu fiz utilizando o Laravel 5 para o meu cliente, porém, eu só tenho acesso ao FTP. Eu instalei o Laravel via composer no meu localhost, funciona muito bem, mas não sei como faço para colocar esse sistema no ar via FTP.
No meu caso, o Laravel precisaria ficar dentro da pasta admin, dessa forma:

```
www.meusite.com.br/portal/admin
```

Já fiz a busca no google, mas o que eu encontrei era só referente a subdomínio

Comment: Toda vez que vou por numa hospedagem eu coloco todos os arquivos dentro da pasta que eu quero. Vamos supor que seja ´admin´. Depois disso é só acessar o LINK e colocar o **/public** no final. **www.meusite.com.br/portal/admin/public**

Comment: Relacionado ou duplicado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43685/problema-com-subpastas-e-reescrita-de-url-com-laravel

Answer (score 2):

O Laravel funciona como o root do seu site, ou seja ele é um framework totalmente orientado a criar todas aplicações, desde o seu dashboard, até múltiplos sub-domínios (veja: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#sub-domain-routing), exemplo:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'), function()
{

    Route::get('user/{id}', function($account, $id)
    {
        //
    });

});
```

Então mesmo que você jogue o seu projeto Laravel em uma pasta como `/etc/www/porta/admin` ou `/public_html/portal/admin` ele não irá reconhecer quando acessar:

- `http://site/portal/admin`

Pois o Laravel vai procurar nas rotas isto `/portal/admin` e não isto `/admin`, portanto a ideia do Laravel é que você projeto com ele todas as páginas, para fazer proveito de todos Views e Models e também tornar a aplicação escalável, assim evitando de criar coisas diferentes pra mesma tarefa. **Note** que só porque você usou Laravel pra criar toda a aplicação não significa que irá conseguir torna-lo escalavel sem ter o conhecimento e experiencia com este tipo de coisa (no entanto isto é fora do assunto aqui)

Felizmente é possível burlar sim as rotas do Laravel e fazer ele ficar acessivel, edite o arquivo `app/Http/routes.php` e edite as rotas adicionando um prefixo `/portal/admin`, então aonde você usa:

```
Route::get('/', ...
```

Vai ficar:

```
Route::get('/portal/admin', ...
```

Um exemplo:

```
$prefixo = '/portal/admin';

//http://site/portal/admin
Route::get($prefixo, function () {
    return view('login');
});

//http://site/portal/admin/dashboard
Route::get($prefixo . '/dashboard', function () {
    //...
});

//http://site/portal/admin/logout
Route::get($prefixo . '/logout', function () {
    //...
});
```

Se o endereço mudar, você terá que trocar todos prefixos `/portal/admin`. Eu não conheço o Laravel a fundo, talvez com `group` seja possível fazer isto mais facilmente.

Note uma coisa muito importante, a pasta `admin` tem que ter o conteúdo do de `public`, portanto as demais pastas do laravel irão ficar fora de `admin`, mas se isto não for possivel, você pode colocar tudo dentro de `admin`, até mesmo a public e criar um .htaccess pra redirecionar, como nestas resposta:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91799/3635

Deve ficar assim no seu caso:

```
./public_html (Pasta root da hospedagem)
    |--- portal
          |--- admin
               |--- .htaccess (arquivo .htaccess que você deve criar)
               |--- /public
                      |--- index.php
                      |--- .htaccess
               |--- /app
               |--- /bootstrap
               |--- /config
               |--- /database
```

O arquivo .htaccess deve ficar assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [L]
```

Quando acessar `http://www.site/portal/admin/` isto fará um total redirecionamento para o arquivo `/public_html/portal/admin/public/index.php`.

Tudo isto chega a ser uma gambiarra, visando que o Laravel foi projetado pra trabalhar como **root** e pode haver algumas dificuldades em usar desta maneira, como outras incompatibilidades possíveis, o que recomendo é começar a pensar em refazer talvez o projeto (na medida do possível).

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, seleciona todas as pastas, arquivos e coloca dentro da pasta admin. O `Laravel` é como se fosse seu site.

Veja na imagem abaixo. Seleciona tudo que tiver nesse diretório e coloca dentro da pasta admin do seu FTP.

Lembrando que vai demorar um pouco visto que são muitos arquivos e pastas do Laravel, fora o seu site.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Então, mas eu ja fiz isso e deu erro

Comment: Qual erro ? O caminho é esse, os erros corigimos.

Comment: Então, vou baixar e subir de novo, ai passo o erro certinho

Comment: Então, quando eu acesso o meu site por esse caminho: www.meusite.com.br/portal/adm, me da esses dois erros:

Warning: require_once(__DIR__/public/index.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/storage/8/28/d5/conre3/public_html/portal/adm/index.php on line 21

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/public/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /home/storage/8/28/d5/conre3/public_html/portal/adm/index.php on line 21

Todo o laravel esá dentro da pasta adm

Comment: Tem algum `.htaccess` em alguma pasta anterior a `admin` do FTP ? Ou dentro da pasta `admin` ? Se sim, poste na sua pergunta juntamente com o erro.

Comment: Nenhum .htacces, nem dentro da portal e nem dentro da admin

Comment: Então, crie um `.htaccess` e coloque dentro da pasta `adm`. Tem que ter isso: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Coloquei la, agora deu erro 500

Comment: 500 ? Veja no arquivo `app.php` a linha `debug = false`, coloque `true` e passa apenas esse arquivo em sua pasta respectiva no FTP. Está em **app/config/app.php**.

Comment: Entao, não tem o app não. Esse Laravel é a versão 5, acho que e um pouco diferente. o app.php que tenho já está dentro da pasta config, e já está como true o debug

Comment: Então, é esse mesmo... ele está direcionando para a página certa ? Tem como você mostrar como está a disposição de pastas do seu 'Laravel' ?

Comment: Então, a disposição está padrão, não alterei nada, do mesmo jeito que veio do composer eu coloquei na pasta adm pelo ftp

Comment: E quando você acessa a página acessa com ou sem o `/public` ?

Comment: Dos dois jeitos da o mesmo problema

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29409/discussion-between-diego-souza-and-daniel-swater).

Comment: Atualizou o PHP, fei ?