# Lista de diretórios do projeto em Laravel é exibida ao invés de executar a aplicação

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, diretório

[image: Projeto Não está funcionando]

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para saber porque o meu projeto PHP com o Framework Laravel não funciona, fiz todos os passos corretamente, porém ao invés de ver o framework, estou vendo as suas pastas

Answer (score 10):

> Note que as instruções passadas aqui são feitas em base do Laravel 5.1, podendo funcionar ou não no Laravel 4.2

A pasta que você tem que acessar é a `public` (eu também me confundi a primeira vez que usei o laravel), isto é um problema comum entre a maioria das pessoas que usam a primeira vez Laravel.

### Laravel em ambiente de desenvolvimento

Você tem 3 opções:

1. Usar o server.php que é um script pra rodar o [php em modo stand-alone](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) (sem apache), pra isso acesse o terminal e vá até a pasta do seu projeto em Laravel:

   ```
   $ cd /home/user/projeto-em-laravel
   $ php -S localhost:8000 server.php
   ```
2. Configurar o Apache pra apontar pra pasta do `public` do Laravel (tem a possibilidade configurar um virtualhost também)

   ```
   DocumentRoot "/home/user/projeto-em-laravel/public"
   <Directory "/home/user/projeto-em-laravel/public">
       AllowOverride all
   </Directory>
   ```
3. Configurar um .htaccess na pasta `./projeto-em-laravel` pra apontar tudo pra pasta `./projeto-em-laravel/public/`, crie na pasta `./projeto-em-laravel` o arquivo `.htaccess` e coloque este conteúdo nele:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On

     RewriteRule ^ /projeto-em-laravel/index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```

### Se for um ambiente de produção

No caso de ambiente de produção **não** use o server.php (mesmo se bem que acho que seria algo quase impossível), sendo o Apache você pode tentar o passo 2 ou 3 já citados, no entanto se o servidor o qual vai instalar o laravel não te da o controle sobre o apache, então tente seguir isto:

1. Geralmente os servidores tem uma pasta chamada `public_html` ou `www` se acessar pelo cpanel (se for o caso) em outros casos a pasta aonde deve jogar os arquivos é o nome do site, por exemplo `./www.meusite.com`.
2. Nestes casos você deve tentar o passo 3 então você vai jogar todo o conteúdo (apenas o conteúdo) da pasta `projeto-em-laravel` na pasta `public_html` por exemplo e deve criar um arquivo `.htaccess` igual ao passo 3, a estrutura de pasta deve ficar assim:

   ```
   ./public_html
      |--- .htaccess
      |--- /public
             |--- index.php
             |--- .htaccess
      |--- /app
      |--- /bootstrap
      |--- /config
      |--- /database
   ```
3. Existem desenvolvedores que simplesmente jogam o conteúdo da pasta `projeto-em-laravel` **fora** de `public_html` e em `public_html` colocam o conteúdo de `./projeto-em-laravel/public`, isto é uma opção também, **mas** você pode acabar se perdendo com as pastas já existentes do servidor, deve ficar algo como:

   ```
   /home/user/
      |--- /access-logs     (pasta padrão em servidores com cpanel)
      |--- /etc             (pasta padrão em servidores com cpanel)
      |--- /public_ftp      (pasta padrão em servidores com cpanel)
      |--- /tmp             (pasta padrão em servidores com cpanel)
      |--- /public_html     (pasta padrão em servidores com cpanel)
             |--- index.php (arquivo da pasta /public)
             |--- .htaccess (arquivo da pasta /public)
      |--- /app             (pasta do seu projeto laravel)
      |--- /bootstrap       (pasta do seu projeto laravel)
      |--- /config          (pasta do seu projeto laravel)
      |--- /database        (pasta do seu projeto laravel)
   ```

### Configurando o Laravel

- Antes de usar o Laravel é necessário criar o arquivo `.env`, note que na pasta laravel existe um arquivo chamado `.env.example` copie ele e de o nome de `.env` se este não existir.
- Então será necessário configurar o `APP_KEY`, ele deve ser uma chave de 32 caracteres, por exemplo:

  ```
  APP_KEY=2XXjEeJYr2jO0lboHZPHLuN6eYmnxPvl
  ```
- Recomendo que use o comando `key:generate` pra gerar a tal chave, note que pra usar o comando `artesian` é necessário ter configurado pelo composer e ter adicionado o artesian as *variáveis de ambiente*, navegue até a pasta de do teu projeto e depois use o comando:

  ```
  $ cd /home/user/laravel
  $ php artisan key:generate
  ```
- Quando for subir o projeto pra produção (pro servidor online) você deverá mudar a linha `APP_DEBUG=true` pra `APP_DEBUG=false`, isto irá desligar os erros que só devem ser exibidos pro ambiente de desenvolvimento e não pro usuário final e também alterar `APP_ENV=local` para `APP_ENV=production`.

### O .env no Laravel em ambiente de desenvolvimento:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=2XXjEeJYr2jO0lboHZPHLuN6eYmnxPvl
```

### O .env no Laravel em ambiente de produção:

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=2XXjEeJYr2jO0lboHZPHLuN6eYmnxPvl
```