# Reescrita de URL no HTACCESS ignorando arquivos e pastas existentes

Tags: laravel, htaccess

Quando vou passar um site no servidor eu coloco um arquivo `.htaccess` com esse código abaixo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Esse código faz com que ao digitar o site:

> www.dominio.com.br

Entre direto no `index.php` da pasta `public` do **Laravel**.

Mas agora está acontecendo um problema. Tenho um painel que está em uma pasta `painel`, fora da pasta `public` do **Laravel**, que é independente do **Laravel**.

Mas quando digito:

> www.dominio.com.br/painel

Não entra.

E mesmo eu colocando a pasta `painel` dentro da pasta `public`, também não entra. Por causa do `.htaccess` dentro da pasta `public`.

Como posso deixar essa URL independente ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto ocorreu porque você não fez a verificação se a pasta existe e um outro detalhe ao invés disto:

```apacheconf
RewriteRule ^painel - [L]
```

Prefira isto:

```apacheconf
RewriteRule ^painel/ - [L]
```

Sem a barra o .htaccess vai aceitar endereços como `localhost/painel2` e supondo que ele seja uma rota ele se tornará inacessivel.

Voltando ao problema, provavelmente você fez algo semelhante a isto no teu .htaccess: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91799/3635

### Primeira solução

Deve estar usando semelhante a isto:

```
/home
  |--- /user
         |--- /public_html
                |--- .htaccess (seu .htaccess)
                |--- /public
                        |--- index.php
                        |--- .htaccess
                |--- /app
                |--- /bootstrap
                |--- /config
                |--- /database
                |--- /painel (pasta do painel)
```

Se quer que a pasta painel aqui seja acessivel o `public_html/.htaccess` deve ficar assim:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/ [L]
```

### Segunda solução

No entanto o melhor é tudo fique dentro de `public` mesmo, então a estrutura seria assim das pastas sendo esta (`public_html` é uma pasta comum em servidores, pode ter outro nome como `www`), veja que mudei o local da pasta painel para dentro de `public`:

```
/home
  |--- /user
         |--- /public_html
                |--- .htaccess (seu .htaccess)
                |--- /public
                        |--- /painel (pasta do painel)
                        |--- index.php
                        |--- .htaccess
                |--- /app
                |--- /bootstrap
                |--- /config
                |--- /database
```

Então neste caso o arquivo `public_html/.htaccess` deve conter:

```apacheconf
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ public/ [L]
```

E o arquivo `public_html/public/.htaccess` deve conter:

```apacheconf
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

### Terceira solução

Mas devo dizer uma coisa, você pode até usar o .htaccess pra apontar tudo para `public`, no entanto o melhor caminho é definir o `DocumentRoot` como sendo o `public` do Laravel ou então soltar o conteudo de `public` em `public_html` e as pastas dos laravel irão ficar fora, algo como:

```
/home
   |--- /user
         |--- /app
         |--- /bootstrap
         |--- /config
         |--- /database
         |--- public_html (conteúdo de public deve ficar nesta pasta)
              |--- /painel (pasta do painel)
              |--- index.php
              |--- .htaccess
```

Answer (score 1):

Mano, esse SO é top.

Acho que tem algum poder que fica pairando por aqui... tem perguntas que eu faço aqui e pouco tempo depois, questão de minutos soluciono meu problema.

Como vocês conseguem ?

Pra deixar a URL 'independente' digitei assim:

```
RewriteRule ^painel - [L]
```

Ficando assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^painel - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```