# Não consigo acessar o meu projeto no laravel 5 usando Xampp

Tags: php, laravel-5

Eu comecei a estudar o **Laravel 5** e eu consegui instalar o **composer** e o **framework php**.

Fiz alguns teste depois da instalação funcionou perfeitamente uma maravilha, desliguei a minha máquina e no dia seguinte quando eu fui estudar novamente o framework, não conseguia mais acessar o que eu já tinha feito o dia anterior.

*Startei* o xampp, abri o navegador e digitei

```
localhost:8000/exemplo
```

E ele não encontra o projeto.

Alguém pode me dizer se eu estou fazendo algo de errado ou falta alguma configuração no `php.ini`?

Comment: Boa noite Bruno, o Xampp não usa porta 8000, a porta no xampp por padrão é 80, ou seja basta acessar http://localhost

Comment: se você tinha acessado a porta **8000** anteriormente, provavelmente vc avia iniciado o servidor pelo próprio PHP(Framework Laravel)

Comment: Foi exatamente o que eu fiz @BrumazziDB, ao instalar o framework ele já estartou junto com o xampp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Xampp não usa porta 8000 por padrão, a porta no xampp (apache) padrão é a porta 80, ou seja basta acessar http://localhost já irá funcionar (pois a porta 80 pode ser omitida na URL).

Note que pra configurar o Laravel no Apache é um pouco mais complexo, no entanto eu já respondi sobre isto neste link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91799/3635 o que ajudar.

É provável que a primeira vez você tenha tentando usar [PHP Built-in server](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.webserver.php), na instalação do Laravel vem um arquivo chamado *server.php*, esse arquivo é usado para desenvolvimento apenas, ou seja o **built-in server** não serve para produção.

Se estiver em desenvolvimento, basta acessar a pasta aonde se localiza o projeto, note que o php vai ter que esta nas variáveis de ambiente, se for Windows:

- Abra o CMD
- Digite o local da pasta assim:

  ```
  cd c:\Users\Bruno\Meus Documents\Projetos\projeto-em-laravel
  php -S localhost:8000 server.php
  ```
- Se for like-unix (mac, linux, etc):

  ```
  cd /home/Bruno/projeto-em-laravel
  php -S localhost:8000 server.php
  ```

Depois abra http://localhost:8000

**Leia mais em:**

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91799/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105653/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105659/3635

### Usando Artisan

O [Artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan) é um sistema de linha de comando (CLI) incluído no laravel, o qual pode ser [customizado](https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan#registering-commands), é possível ver todos os comandos rodando isto (no terminal ou cmd):

```
 php artisan list
```

Também é possível chamar o webserver [PHP Built-in server](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.webserver.php) usando o Artisan:

```
 php artisan serve
```

Pra customizar o endereço e porta:

```
 php artisan serve --host=503.246.895.41 --port=8125
```

Comment: Por que o downvote? Explique -.-' !!!

Comment: Não entendi também

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento fuçando na net eu encontrei um artigo que falava sobre o seguinte comando: `php artisan serve` na pasta do meu projeto. E eu fiz isso e funcionou, agora por curiosidade gostaria de saber. O que esse comando quer dizer? Por que eu tenho que digitar esse comando para funcionar o meu projeto?

Comment: @BrunoDuarte `Artisan` é um script php pra usar com CLI, ele tem uma série de comando, basicamente este que você usou é um atalho para o exemplo da minha resposta, mas existem outros comandos no Artisan, veja isto: https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan

Comment: Entendi @GuilhermeNascimento, valeu pela dica. Abraço!