# Rota não executa método do controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Boa tarde.
Estou com um problema no meu código php desenvolvido em Laravel 4.
Tenho uma função em JavaScript que executa uma ação usando o $.post e em caso de sucesso, chama outra função Javascript, esta segunda usando $.ajax. As duas em páginas do .blade.
O problema é que ao entrar na segunda função, desconfio que a rota passada no campo url não é encontrada, mas não encontro o erro. Alguém pode me ajudar?
Seguem os códigos:

funções Javascript:

```
function form_variations_submit()
{
    $.post(
        '{{route('admin.ajax.save')}}',
        $('#form').serialize(),
        function(data) {
            if(data.sucesso) {
                alert("Alterações Salvas! "+data.pvid);
                var pvid = data.pvid;
                alert("pvid = "+pvid);
                var flagOrder = envia_pvid(pvid);
                alert("FlagOrder = "+flagOrder);
            } else {
                alert(data.erro);
            }
        }
    );
    return false;
}

function envia_pvid(id){
    var pId = id;
    alert("Entrou na 2 função! Envia_id "+ pId);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{route('admin.ordem')}}',
        data: { pId : pId
        },
        sucess: function(data) {
            if(data.pvid){
                var ret = data.pvid;
                alert(ret);
                return ret;
            } else{
                alert("ERRO!");
            }
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

Rota:

```
Route::post('p_var', array('as' => 'admin.ordem', 'uses' => 'Admin_Controller@setaOrdem'));
```

Função setaOrdem presente no Controller:

```
public function setaOrdem()
{
    $pvid = Input::get('pId');

    return Response::json(array('sucesso' => true,'pvid' => $pvid));
}
```

Os alerts são executados nomalmente até o alert do FlagOrder que devolve "undefined".

Comment: Quando a página é renderizada o que aparece no lugar de `'{{route('admin.ajax.save')}}'`?

Comment: Ao inspecionar o elemento aparece: http://..../admin/ajax_save (nome real da função corresponde a admin.ajax.save)

Comment: Vou supor que o `http://....` seja abreviado. A rota `/admin/ajax_save` existe? Como você declarou ela? Na sua pergunta apenas no o `as` para `admin.ordem`

Comment: Sim os '...' é a abreviação da url que tem o nome do servidor local que está rodando a aplicação e a hierarquia de pastas do projeto.
Declarei a rota anterior do mesmo jeito que declarei a rota que não está sendo executada: 
'Route::post('ajax_save', array('as' => 'admin.ajax.save', 'uses' => 'Admin_Controller@ajax_save'));'

Comment: Aconselho você a debugar na console do google chrome.

Comment: Isto pode ser o problema então, até aonde sei a pasta `public` do Laravel deve ser usado como o path principal, usando VirtualHost por exemplo, se estiver em uma subpasta provavelmente você terá que apontar ela também.

Comment: então, mas para a primeira função tudo executa normalmente, porém para a segunda função, localizada na mesma pasta, que executa uma função no mesmo controller que a anterior, não acontece nada.
Eu acho que o erro é na rota, mas posso estar errado.

Comment: Seria interessante você separar o PHP do javascript. Você usou a sintaxe do blade no meio do javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vou lhe passar algumas dicas que podem lhe auxiliar na resolução do problema:

**Primeiro gostaria de ressaltar sobre o Javascript**.

O que difére o `$.post` do jQuery referente ao `$.ajax` é que o $.post não possui a chave error para fazer tratamentos de erros, já $.ajax possui. Então se uma função depende da outra em caso de sucesso, aconselho você utilizar $.ajax nas duas função para capturar os erros:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '//sua url',
  type: 'tipo da requisição',
  data: //dados de envio,
  success: function(response)
 {
    //retorno
 },
 error: function(xhr)
 {
   console.log(xhr.responseText);
 }
});
```

Isso é importante porque certos tipos de erros só são possíveis capturar através da função error e muitas pessoas não sabem as diferenças entre o `$.post`, `$.get` e `$.ajax`. Mas isso foi apenas uma dica, essa situação não interfere na localização da rota.

**Agora sobre o Laravel**

Reparei que você está utilizando rotas nomeadas. Como você não deixou esplicito a url real vou exemplificar os possíveis erros:

**Criação das rotas no laravel**

Quando você utiliza rotas fazendo requisição `POST`

```
Route::post('url','Controller@metodo');
```

Para `GET`

```
Route::get('url/{identificador}','Controller@metodo');
```

Para qualquer requisição

```
Route::any('url','Controller@metodo');
```

Caso você esteja em localhost e não criou o virtual host você tem que especificar a url completa no javascript para que a rota seja encontrada. Já em produção não possui esse problema caso esteja configurado o apontamento para a pasta public. Se você criou o virtual host é importante você passar a URL da seguinte forma:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/url real não nomeada' //EX: '/admin/ajax-savar-dados'
});
```

Não aconselho você utilizar a rota nomeada no javascript. Primeiro porque é uma péssima pratica colocar o PHP no meio do javascript. Pode até ser um dos motivos dos erros. O ideal é você colocar o javascript em em arquivo separado.

para testar sua requisição $.ajax utilize o console do navegador na opção

**network > xhr**

Answer (score 0):

Se olhar na aba network nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do seu navegador provavelmente irá notar o erro 404.

Pelo que entendi a pasta `public` do seu projeto não é a pasta principal, o Laravel pra funcionar corretamente precisa que a pasta `public` seja o `root` do servidor (por exemplo apache), pois senão você terá que declarar as subpastas e isto ficará difícil na hora de mover pra produção.

O Laravel funciona exatamente assim, orientado a pasta `public` do seu projeto, como ela sendo a principal de tudo, se o seu projeto estiver em uma pasta assim:

- `/etc/www/projeto1`

E você tentar acessar:

- `http://localhost/projeto1/` ou `http://localhost/projeto1/public/`

As rotas não vão entender o caminho, pois elas trabalham a partir do primeiro `/` após o `localhost` na url `http://localhost/`

### Apache:

Se for o Apache você pode alterar o documentroot:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/user/projeto-em-laravel/public"
<Directory "/home/user/projeto-em-laravel/public">
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

### Ngnix:

No Nginx você usa o `root` pra apontar:

```
root /home/user/projeto-em-laravel/public/;
```

Estes exemplos são pra desenvolvimento, pra produção provavelmente você terá que editar o virtualhost, ou fazer que nem nesta resposta:

- [Laravel não está funcionando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91799/3635)

Comment: Então, mas o Network não apresenta erro, o console tbm não apresenta erro algum! Simplesmente não executa, não muda a URL, nem nada.

Comment: @JoabNunes O erro deve ser verificado não só no momento que faz o load na página, mas também no momento que faz as requisições ajax. A aba network deve apresentar códigos como 200 (Ok), 404 (NotFound) e 500 (Internal error server). O laravel pode até apresentar "200 ok", mas isto pode ser porque o seu mod_rewrite esta desabilitado. Eu editei a resposta. Veja a parte que explico *"O Laravel funciona exatamente assim, orientado a pasta public do seu projeto"*.