# Controller puxando dados do banco de um lugar errado

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, banco-de-dados

Tenho a aplicação devidamente configurada e rodando normalmente. Mas um detalhe está emperrando.

Esse é o meu arquivo .env:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=9FaEj6iJCBur1favtWQ88b8m1anbGbzP
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=laravel_blog
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
...
```

Quando executo o comando `env('DB_DATABASE','forge')` no tinker, é retornado o valor `laravel_blog`, como deveria ser.

No entanto quando faço exatamente a mesma operação dentro de um controller, é retornado o valor `homestead`, não deveria retornar isso

A seguir como está a conexão com o banco:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

Acaba criando a situação que o banco roda no tinker, mas no controller não funciona, por que pega os dados da conexão errados.

O problema é que não faço a menor ideia de onde o laravel está puxando o valor da constante,dentro do controller, já que no .env o valor configurado é diferente.

Comment: Poderia postar teu código para obter uma análise melhor.

Comment: ok atualizei....

Comment: qual a versão do laravel utilizada?

Comment: estou usando o 5

Comment: Você está usando o Homestead?

Answer (score 1):

Verifique a sua conexão padrão no arquivo database.php, e veja se está com o nome da conexão que vc postou aqui, no caso "`mysql`"

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')
```

Altere essas linhas do seu database.php

```
'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
```

De uma olhada no arquivo  `~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml` na parte:

```
databases:
    - homestead
```

Comment: Fiz o que você passou, dê uma olhada no retorno do debug (lembrando do que eu passei lá no post): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=homestead', 'homestead', 'secret', array('0', '2', '0', false, '0'))  Ele está puxando esses dados de algum lugar que não é o .env

Comment: bom, vc esta usando homestead né, eu sinceramente estou por fora, pois não configurei isso aqui. Sei que tem um arquivo chamado "homestead.yaml" em algum canto ai, e creio que seja nele que esteja a configuração que o controller está puxando.

Comment: Da uma fuçada aí ou busca na net que vc deve achar, eu infelizmente não sei dizer mais que isso rs.

Comment: obrigado de qualquer jeito

Comment: nada, editei minha resposta, creio muito que seja esse mesmo o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendo muito de Laravel, eu acredito que o seu exemplo:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Seja o default do Laravel, é apenas um exemplo, acredito que você possa trocar os nomes facilmente editando `/config/database.php`:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'laravel_blog',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Se você tiver apenas um banco de dados então você pode editar o seu arquivo `.env`, note que existem mais de um arquivo `.env`, são:

- `.env`, `.env.example` e `.env.production`

Você deve alterar o `.env` os demais não, pois eles são apenas exemplos, no .env existem estas variáveis:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Basta editar para algo como no exemplo:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=laravel_blog
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Isso se você tiver apenas um banco, se o arquivo .env ainda não existe então leia a seguir:

### Configurando o Laravel

- Antes de usar o Laravel como eu disse [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91799/3635) é necessário criar o arquivo `.env`, note que na pasta laravel existe um arquivo chamado `.env.example` copie ele e de o nome de `.env` se este não existir.
- Então será necessário configurar o `APP_KEY`, ele deve ser uma chave de 32 caracteres, por exemplo:

  ```
  APP_KEY=2XXjEeJYr2jO0lboHZPHLuN6eYmnxPvl
  ```
- Recomendo que use o comando `key:generate` pra gerar a tal chave, note que pra usar o comando `artesian` é necessário ter configurado pelo composer e ter adicionado o artesian as *variáveis de ambiente*, navegue até a pasta de do teu projeto e depois use o comando:

  ```
  $ cd /home/user/laravel
  $ php artisan key:generate
  ```
- Quando for subir o projeto pra produção (pro servidor online) você deverá mudar a linha `APP_DEBUG=true` pra `APP_DEBUG=false`, isto irá desligar os erros que só devem ser exibidos pro ambiente de desenvolvimento e não pro usuário final e também alterar `APP_ENV=local` para `APP_ENV=production`.

### O .env no Laravel em ambiente de desenvolvimento:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=2XXjEeJYr2jO0lboHZPHLuN6eYmnxPvl
```

### O .env no Laravel em ambiente de produção:

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=2XXjEeJYr2jO0lboHZPHLuN6eYmnxPvl
```

Comment: eu nao gostaria de editar diretamente o arquivo de configuraçao do database, eu queria que ele pegasse os dados da conexão do .env, mas ele tá pegando de não sei onde. Mexi lá no .env.example e também não causou efeito... Não faço a menor ideia de onde o laravel está tirando os dados da conexão com o banco, já que alterei todos os arquivos .env

Comment: @AdrianoLuz Mas foi o que eu disse, não é pra mexer no `.env.example` e `.env.production`, eles são exemplos apenas, o arquivo correto é apenas `.env`, se ele ainda não existe, então leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91799/3635 (aonde esta escrito Configurando o Laravel) :)

Comment: ele existe e está sim, quando tendo testar o banco pelo tinker ele encontra dos dados do .env, no entanto dentro do controler ele puxa os dados de outro lugar

Comment: @AdrianoLuz Eu coloquei aquilo apenas como um explicação de como criar o .env acaso não exista, você deve ler a resposta inteira, eu também postei como editar o .env, você deve verificar o conteúdo dele. Abra a pasta do teu projeto e edite o arquivo .env com o sublimetext e veja o conteudo.

Comment: Olha só uma coisa curiosa, eu foi lá no .env e criei constantes personalizadas MY_DB, MY_USER, MY_PASS, com os valores laravel_blog/root/em branco. Depois fui lá no config/database e realizei as alterações no env(), ok achou, está rodando. Mas ainda não faço a menor ideia do que está alterando os valores das constantes DB_DATABASE/DB_USERNAME/DB_PASSWORD para respectivamente homestead/homestead/secret, quando executo o controller.

Comment: @AdrianoLuz mas como estão os valor no .env de DB_DATABASE/DB_USERNAME/DB_PASSWORD? Você execultou alguma vez a função `env` em algum outro arquivo?

Comment: Sim funciona no tinker, mas quando é num controller ele encontra outros valores para essas constantes. No .env está configurado laravel_blog/root/em branco, porém quando executo ele puxa homestead/homestead/secret

Comment: @AdrianoLuz por favor, responda ao que é perguntado, eu te pergunto uma coisa e você esta falando algo que já esta claro na sua pergunta. Vou ser sincero acho que você esta se confundindo. Primeiro que no tinker você disparou `env('DB_DATABASE','forge')` ao invés de `env('DB_DATABASE')`, outra coisa não você tem que verificar se não há mais de um projeto. Você navegou até a pasta correta pelo terminal? Usando o vim no mesmo terminal ou outro editor de texto pra abrir o .env? Tem muita coisa aqui que não esta dando pra entender o que você fez. Espero que entenda como uma critica construtiva ;)