# Como acessar o diretório public do Storage no Laravel 5.3?

Tags: imagem, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Preciso acessar imagens salvas no diretório `/storage/app/public` nas `views`, porém não consigo, tenho um `404`.

*Estou fazendo o seguinte:*

```
<div class="row">
    <img src="../storage/app/public/3.jpg">
</div>
```

Mas ele não encontra a imagem.

Existe algum `helper` do `Laravel` que acesse essa pasta?

Comment: tente direto 3.jpg, o public é a raiz do projeto

Comment: @DouglasCarvalho Na verdade é uma pasta com nome public dentro de `Storage/app`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se `storage/public` se refere a algo como `/home/user/projeto-em-laravel/public/storage/public` eu acho que seria interessante mudar sua estratégia, a pasta `storage` não deve ser acessada diretamente e nem vai conseguir, a não ser que tenha feito algo muito errado, o correto é usar a função `asset`, assim:

```
echo asset('storage/file.txt');
```

Conforme a documentação https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#the-public-disk

O disco público destina-se a arquivos que serão publicamente acessíveis. Por padrão, o disco público usa o disco local e armazena esses arquivos em `storage/app/public`.

Para torná-los acessíveis a partir da web, você pode criar um link simbólico de `public/storage` para `storage/app/public`.

Para criar o link simobilico você deve executar o comando:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Uma vez criado, você pode criar um url e usar a função do "helper" chamada `asset` dentro de uma rota:

```
echo asset('storage/file.txt');
```

Você pode acessar assim (não tenho certeza se tem que digitar o prefixo `public/`):

```
<img src="storage/3.jpg">
```

<s>Não é correto fazer isso, o public na verdade deve representar o `root` de uma página HTTP, por exemplo no Apache configuraria assim:</s>

```
DocumentRoot "/home/user/projeto-em-laravel/public"
<Directory "/home/user/projeto-em-laravel/public">
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

Então as imagens seriam acessíveis assim:

```
<img src="3.jpg">
```

Se estiver na pasta `/home/user/projeto-em-laravel/public/images/3.jpg`, ficaria assim:

```
<img src="images/3.jpg">
```

Se estiver for `images/3.jpg` usar em background em um CSS assim `/home/user/projeto-em-laravel/public/css/meucss.css` então deve usar o `../`, assim:

```
seletor {
    background: url(../images/3.jpg);
}
```

> Leia mais em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91799/3635

Comment: Na verdade é uma pasta com nome public dentro de `Storage/app`

Comment: `Storage` é uma pasta apenas para armazenar dados, você deve redirecionar ela como rota preferencialmente, vou tenta fazer algo como laravel ou diretamente no .htaccess.

Comment: Diretório é `./app/storage/app/public/3.jpg`, o problema é que nao consigo acessar ele da view

Comment: @FelipePaetzold resposta editada