# Laravel 5.3 Route não aceita parametros alem do "/"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, route

Bom dia. 
Sou novo no laravel e instalei o 5.3 com php 5.6. Ao começar definir as rotas deparei com a situação de que o método `Route::get()` no primeiro argumento só aceita "/". Quando tentei definir outra rota como por exemplo `Route::get("/empresa", 'FrontController@empresa');` ele retorna sempre "Método não permitido! O método GET não é permitido para o URL pedido." ou seja, a única rota que consigo definir é "/" alem dessa retorna sempre esse erro.

Grato pela vossa ajuda.

ERRO:

> Método não permitido! O método GET não é permitido para o URL pedido. If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.28

Comment: Não precisa de colocar a `/`.

Comment: continua o mesmo erro, já tentei assim também

Comment: Como você está acessando a página ? Poste seu arquivo de rotas e seu controller, por favor.

Comment: Método não permitido!

O método GET não é permitido para o URL pedido.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.28

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e poste seu arquivo de rotas e seu controller, por favor.

Comment: Erro 404 é provavel que não tenha configurado o Laravel adequadamente esta resposta deve resolver seu problema http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91799/3635

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e poste seu arquivo de rotas e seu controller, por favor.

Comment: Ja descobri. Foi exatamente mal configurado conforme a link que voce me passou. Obrigado

Comment: Por nada ;) Até mais