# Como hospedar um site laravel no windows server?

Tags: laravel, aplicação-web, servidor, ip, host

O computador onde quero hospedar o site desenvolvido em laravel fica em outra rede. Coloquei todo o site no servidor e rodei o comando

```
php artisan serve --host MEUIP --port MEUPORTO
```

Quando vou testar em outro computador o browser responde que a pagina demorou muito para responder ? Qual o procedimento correto para hospedar o site laravel em outra maquina ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Esta usando IIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provavelmente pretende usar IIS sendo Windows Server, no caso você pode ter instalado um destes programas:

- IIS "padrão"
- IIS Express
- WebPlatformInstaller

### Se for IIS padrão ou IIS Express

> Se estiver usando WebPlatformInstaller não faça este procedimento a seguir.

Primeiro instale o PHP:

Baixe em http://windows.php.net/download/
E instale na pasta `%SYSTEMROOT%\php` (exemplos `c:\php` ou `d:\php`)

---

### Passos para instalar PHP no IIS padrão

Depois de instalar o PHP, navegue até `%windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\` e então edite o `applicationHost.config` e então adicione algo como (editando os locais já existentes dentro do config):

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
    <files>
        <add value="index.php" />
        <add value="Default.htm" />
        <add value="Default.asp" />
        <add value="index.htm" />
        <add value="index.html" />
        <add value="iisstart.htm" />
    </files>
</defaultDocument>

<fastCgi>
    <application
        fullPath="C:\php\php-cgi.exe"
        monitorChangesTo="C:\php\php.ini"
        activityTimeout="300"
        requestTimeout="300"
        instanceMaxRequests="10000"
    >
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="PHPRC" value="C:\php\" />
            <environmentVariable name="PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" value="10000" />
        </environmentVariables>
    </application>
</fastCgi>
```

E depois adicione isto dentro de `handlers`:

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
    <add
        name="PHP_via_FastCGI"
        path="*.php"
        verb="*"
        modules="FastCgiModule"
        scriptProcessor="C:\php\php-cgi.exe"
        resourceType="Either"
    />
```

Depois de instalado digite isto no executar: `%SYSTEMROOT%\inetpub\wwwroot` e pode instalar o Laravel dentro dela, podendo ser uma pasta ou diretamente na pasta `wwwroot`.

---

### Passos para instalar PHP no IIS Express

#### Download

- IIS Express: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48264
- PHP Windows: http://windows.php.net/download/

#### Instalando PHP e IIS Express

Instale o PHP em uma pasta como `C:\php`

Troque `fullPath='"C:\php\php-cgi.exe"'` e `scriptProcessor='"C:\php\php-cgi.exe"` pelo caminho que fez a instalação

Se tiver instalado o IIS x64:

```
cd C:\Program Files\IIS Express\
```

Se tiver instalado o IIS x86:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\
```

Depois digite:

```
appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/fastCGI /+[fullPath='"C:\php\php-cgi.exe"']
appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/handlers /+[name='PHP_via_FastCGI',path='*.php',verb='*',modules='FastCgiModule',scriptProcessor='"C:\php\php-cgi.exe"',resourceType='Unspecified']
```

#### Editando o applicationhost.config

Se tiver entradas repetidas como para o `PHP_via_FastCGI`

```
cd %userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config
notepad.exe applicationhost.config
```

Ou usando SublimeText ou notepad++ ou outro editor selecione algo como <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Open File</kbd>

```
%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

E procure repetidos:

```
<add name="PHP_via_FastCGI" path="*.php"
```

---

### Instalando PHP com WebPlatformInstaller

> Este é o único que não segue os passos acima, pois a instalação é quase toda automatizada e ao meu ver o caminho mais fácil de todos

#### Download

Faça download do WebPlatformInstaller:

- https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

#### Instalando o IIS

- Selecione IIS-Webserver:

  [image: WebPlatform IIS-Webserver]
- Digite "php" e instale as versões desejadas exceto Express, por exemplo:

  [image: WebPlatform php]
- E digite "rewrite":

  [image: Rewrite]

Se você notar uma mensagem assim:

[image: PHP is not enabled register new PHP version to enable PHP via FastCGI]

Então depois clique em `Register new PHP version` e navegue até a pasta aonde instalou o PHP, depois de selecionar deve ficar assim:

[image: PHP WebPlatformInstaller]

---

Todas sugestões aqui servem para qualquer aplicação escrita em PHP, não só Laravel

### Configurando o Laravel

Depois de colocar o laravel na pasta desejada você deve mover conteúdo da pasta do teu projeto para a pasta "root" do seu IIS (se for IIS padrão deve ser a `wwwroot`) e criar dentro da pasta um arquivo chamado `web.config` com este conteúdo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Laravel Force public">
                    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Laravel Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Acaso não exista

### Laravel em ambiente de produção

Note que ao usar o laravel para produção deve desligar o DEBUG mudando no `.env`, então troque isto:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
```

por isto:

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

---

Fontes:

- https://gist.github.com/brcontainer/c2b3c75439fa3e4905e9
- https://github.com/inphinit/inphinit#iis
- https://github.com/inphinit/inphinit/wiki/PHP-com-IIS
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91799/3635

Comment: A primeira parte eu fazia quando não tinha o Wizard prático, mas, agora só uso a segunda... rs

Comment: @VirgilioNovic em 2006 quando comecei a brincar com asp.net eu aborrecido de não existir algo como o WebPlatformInstaller e o PHP ter coisas como Wamp e Xampp, hoje felizmente temos ele :)

Comment: E quando era pra instalar `apache` com PHP ... trampo da pega!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic felizmente no PHP quando comecei já existia o Xampp :D

Comment: Quando digito %SYSTEMROOT%\inetpub\wwwroot  fala que a pasta C:Winows/inetPub não está disponível. Como corrigir ?

Comment: @TúlioParreira mas esta usando qual tipo de instalação IIS, IIS Express ou webplatform? O `%SYSTEMROOT%\inetpub\wwwroot` é somente para o IIS padrão que geralmente é instalado pelo proprio sistema operacional.

Comment: Estou usando o web Plataform.

Comment: @TúlioParreira qual a pasta root do teu IIS?

Comment: Deu certo. Valeu.