# Erro Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. em laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Estou com um problema nesse [site](http://jetwash.com.br/) ele aparece esse erro na tela quando tento acessa-lo [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
oque pode ser esse erro como faço para conserta-lo.

Meus routes:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::post('/', 'FormController@postContato');
```

O .HTACCESS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
# Habilitar o PHP 5.5
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php55/lib
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Está com problema de rotas. Está acessando uma rota inexistente. Coloca o código do **routes.php** e do seu Controller principal que é para abrir a página principal.

Comment: Como seu `.htaccess` está configurado? Está usando servidor compartilhado ou dedicado? Geralmente, em compartilhado não dá pra configurar o apontamento (pelo Apache).

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43685/problema-com-subpastas-e-reescrita-de-url-com-laravel

Comment: Nessa aqui também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88265/publicar-laravel-5-em-uma-subpasta

Comment: Vou editar meu post com essas infos

Comment: Posta o FormController também

Comment: @WallaceMaxters editei meu post da uma olhada

Comment: @Gumball Editei meu post da uma olhada

Comment: É mesmo. Bobeira minha falar isso.

Comment: @Kirito curiosidade: Você publicou o Laravel na Pasta "public_html"? ou algo parecido com uma "pasta principal"? Se for, pode ser esse o problema. Como eu disse, é muito comum em servidores compartilhados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pasta `/public` e não a pasta será considerada uma rota, se fizer isto vai aparecer:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/public', function () {
    return 'Olá, mundo!';
});
```

> Não use o public, é somente para entender as rotas

O problema é que você não entendeu muito bem como Laravel funciona, você tem que configurar a pasta `./public` como pasta padrão do Apache.

Nesta resposta eu explico como usar em ambiente de produção e desenvolvimento:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91799/3635

Comment: Amigo ele gera a urlcom dominio normal porem ele acrecenta http://jetwash.com.br/#form-contact

Comment: @Kirito entendi, após o POST (envio do Form). Por favor posta o conteudo do controller `FormController@postContato` na pergunta