# Problema routes Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estou usando usando o Laravel 5.3 e no curso que estou fazendo pede para no routes colocar a seguinte linha:

```
Route::get('/produtos', 'ProdutoController@lista');
```

Mas colocando dessa forma da um erro:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Para funcionar tenho que colocar:

```
Route::get('/', 'ProdutoController@lista');
```

Mas ao colocar outra pagina para detalhar os produtos não funciona mais ao colocar por exemplo:

```
Route::get('/mostra', 'ProdutoController@mostra');
```

Comment: Você tá tentando acessar a rota corretamente? Qual link você chama?

Comment: Htaccess tá certinho?

Comment: Eu estou acessando : http://localhost/estoque/public/ e ele acessa a lista de produtos. Mas para chamar os detalhes do produto preciso colocar:  Route::get('/', 'ProdutoController@lista'); perdendo o acesso ao método lista. O que não está funcionando é colocar o '/produtos no get'. O .htaccess está o padrão, não alterei nada.

Comment: Está errado! Não deveria acessar a pasta public. `public` é raiz da aplicação escrita em laravel.

Answer (score 1):

O erro está ocorrendo porque a leitura da aplicação está sendo feita a partir pasta raiz do Laravel e não da pasta `public`.

Se você estiver usando o Apache, é necessário que a sua aplicação aponte para a pasta `public` do seu projeto Laravel.

Pois como o Laravel usa internamente o `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` para capturar a requisição, ao invés de ele capturar `/produtos`, ele teria que capturar `/public/produtos`.

Então, é necessário que você configure corretamente o apontamento.

Pelo comentário que você fez, deu a entender que você tem uma aplicação escrita com laravel, porém você está tentando acessar ela como subpastas.

Isso geralmente não dá muito certo, pois o Laravel foi pensando de forma a ser rodado na raiz.

Você pode tentar fazer alguns truques como abaixo, mas não é uma boa ideia.

[Problema com subpastas e reescrita de url com Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43685/problema-com-subpastas-e-reescrita-de-url-com-laravel)

Comment: O problema é que o laravel não esta funcionando corretamente. Ao acessar localhost:8000 ele da o erro: FatalThrowableError in Encrypter.php line 73:
Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt() Ja vi esse erro aqui mas tudo q fiz não deu certo

Comment: "O laravel não está funcionando corretamente" é uma afirmação incorreta. Na verdade, você não configurou o PHP corretamente. Você precisa habilitar o módulo `ssl`. Mas isso não foi descrito na pergunta antes, então sugiro que faça uma nova pergunta, para não mudar o contexto da atual.

Comment: Na verdade os módulos necessários estavam todos instalados. Formatei o computador e funcionou normalmente.